# Continous extension of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, continuity, fibonacci-numbers

If we consider the sequence $a_n = (n-1)!$ then the Gamma function $\Gamma(n)$ gives exactly $a_n$ at each positive integer $n$.

Let $F_n$ denote $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number. Does there exist a continous function $F(x)$ such that $F(n) = F_n$ at each positive integer $n$?

If it exists should it be unique ?

Comment: A function of course exists :D but it is interesting what conditions make it unique (if I remember well for the Gamma function for example it was that its logarithm was a convex function but I may not remember correctly...)...

Comment: The formula $F_n=\frac 1{\sqrt 5}\times \left( \left(\frac {1+\sqrt 5}2\right)^n-\left(\frac {1-\sqrt 5}2\right)^n\right)$ defines such a function.  Of course it is not unique.

Comment: Well, $F(x)=\frac{\sqrt5}5\left(\frac{\sqrt5+1}2\right)^x-\frac{\sqrt5}5\cos(\pi x)\left(\frac{\sqrt5-1}2\right)^x$ is certainly one of them, but I recall hearing that the importance of $\Gamma(n)$ is being the unique extension among the functions with certain properties. I think it was something like being convex on $[0,1]$ and satisfying $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$.

Comment: @lulu I don't think you want to extend that formula to $n\in\Bbb R$, because $\frac{1-\sqrt5}2<0$.

Comment: @Gae.S.  Ah, good point.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3821450,  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/177065, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Extension_to_all_real_or_complex_numbers